# Harness and Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I see that you can trigger a jenkins job in the harness workflow as explained here. Is there a way to trigger a gitlab pipeline from harness ?

https://docs.harness.io/article/5fzq9w0pq7-using-the-jenkins-command

Another question is can I trigger a specific job of an existing gitlab pipeline ?